# What is the verb for first-authorship?

Tags: writing, cv

I am helping someone write his CV. In the publications section, he wrote the following.

> Authored an article titled "Dense Neural Network ...

Now, he was the first/main author for said article. Is it okay if he writes the following?

> First-authored an article titled "Dense Neural Network ...

Should he instead write the following?

> Authored (first/main author) an article titled: Dense Neural Network

Comment: Why use this kind of phrasing at all and not just provide a list of publications? From there it is easy to see which author position the person holds for each publication. After all, it is a CV and not a story.

Comment: To expand on Sursula's point, they should look at what CV's in their area look like. To me this question indicates that they might not have done so.

Comment: @Sursula "After all, it is a CV and not a story" I think viewing these as completely distinct is a mistake.

Comment: @JohnMadden can you elaborate? Because a story usually isn't succinct, and succinctness and precision is essential for a CV because most professors don't have the time or patience to read a whole story...

Comment: @JohnMadden Isn't the whole point of a CV to give a quick and comprehensive overview over the skills, experiences and achievements? In a story format all that will not be easy to extract.

Comment: @Sursula You are probably describing a [resume](https://icc.ucdavis.edu/materials/resume/resumecv).

Comment: @Sursula Some grant applications ask for a "narrative CV" these days so in that context it could be relevant. I agree that for a traditional CV they should just provide a list.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The publications section of a CV normally contains nothing more than a list of one's publications in numbered list (or sometimes bullet list) format. Any sentences with verbs or additional descriptive language would simply clutter up the document and add nothing. In particular, any use of the word "author" (or variants such as "first author") is redundant; this is a publication list in a CV, so obviously the person whose CV this is is representing themselves as an author of the papers being listed. Authorship order is indicated by listing all the author's names. The name of the CV's subject is often put in bold for emphasis, which makes it easy to see where they are in the list of authors. E.g.:

Good:

> **Publications**
>
> 1. **A. Person**, B. Another-Person. Our fabulous paper. *Journal of Interesting Things* 11 (2022), 123-456.
> 2. C. Yet-Another-Person, B. Another-Person, **A. Person**. Another paper. *Journal of Less Interesting Things* 33 (2021), 999-1023.

Not good:

> **Publications**
>
> - First-authored the paper "Our fabulous paper". Appeared in *Journal of Interesting Things* 11 (2022), 123-456. Jointly written with B. Another-Person.
> - Authored the paper "Another paper", which was published in *Journal of Less Interesting Things* 33 (2021), 999-1023. Jointly written with C. Yet-Another-Person and B. Another-Person. (I am the last author.)

As for the grammar question about whether "first-author" can be used as a verb: in a different context where you are writing a text with a more traditional narrative structure, I would say it is grammatically acceptable, but doesn't come across as particularly beautiful or elegant writing. It may make sense in contexts where space is limited, such as to meet a word or page limit or where the writing is generally expected to be on the telegraphic side (as in a brief bio-sketch included with a grant proposal).

Answer (score 2):

While this is, at best, marginally on topic here, the proper verb is "to be" in one of its forms. When writing about self:

"I am the first author..."

When writing about another person "X is the first..." if they are living or "was" if they are deceased.

Answer (score 2):

If first-authorship represents the primary contributor to the paper (and it might or might not depending on the field) then I would recommend that this person instead refer to themselves as having *primary authorship* rather than first authorship.  (And of course, if first authorship is just a coincidence based on extraneous factors like surname, don't mention it at all.)  This approach would lead to something like this:

> Primary-authorship of "Dense Neural Network ..."